HTML encoding and decoding in react native
I am making a texting app in react native, who's data could be accessed via my website for mods. so
in my NodeJS server, when a body is passed in, I used a package that auto-converts characters like < to &lt;. so when it is rendered in my website it transforms &lt; to < but the risk of xss is reduced. however in my react native app, it appears as &lt;. so what is the solution? I know react native can do HTML character encoding but if it was in a hard coded string.
here is a sample code:
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

export function filterXSSMiddleWare() {
  return (req: Request, _res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    for (let i in req.body) {
      req.body[i] = filterXSS(req.body[i]);
      //sure I should filter more than the body, but this is just a sample code
    }
    next();
  };
}

Note: I know I should mainly focus on client side (which is what I do too), but for analytical/personal purposes I want to filter from website.
